# Record not traced into DB using WSO2 DSS

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am performing **DSS operation** in **WSO2 EI 6.1.1**. while checking DSS Operation in management console,records getting traced into DB, but when i tried to execute the same through coding, records are not traced into DB, but getting Successful as response if i put  after endpoint call. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong here?

**DataService(XML):**

```
<data name="CarSalesDSS" transports="http https local">
   <config enableOData="false" id="CarSales_DataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
      <property name="url">url</property>
      <property name="username">username</property>
      <property name="password">password</property>
      <property name="autoCommit">true</property>
      <property name="dataSourceProps"/>
      <property name="dynamicUserAuthMapping">
         <configuration/>
      </property>
   </config>
   
   <query id="Staging_Leads_Query" useConfig="CarSales_DataSource">
      <sql>insert into :Staging_LeadsTable(LeadID,Type,Salutation,FirstName,LastName,Email,MobilePhone) &#xd;values (:LeadID,:Type,:Salutation,:FirstName,:LastName,:Email,:MobilePhone)&#xd; ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Type =:Type,Salutation =:Salutation,FirstName =:FirstName,LastName =:LastName,Email =:Email,MobilePhone =:MobilePhone</sql>
      <param name="Staging_LeadsTable" sqlType="QUERY_STRING"/>
      <param name="LeadID" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="Salutation" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="Type" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="FirstName" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="LastName" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="Email" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="MobilePhone" sqlType="STRING"/>
   </query>
   
   <operation name="Staging_Leads_Opr" returnRequestStatus="true">
      <call-query href="Staging_Leads_Query">
         <with-param name="Staging_LeadsTable" query-param="Staging_LeadsTable"/>
         <with-param name="LeadID" query-param="LeadID"/>
         <with-param name="Salutation" query-param="Salutation"/>
         <with-param name="Type" query-param="Type"/>
         <with-param name="FirstName" query-param="FirstName"/>
         <with-param name="LastName" query-param="LastName"/>
         <with-param name="Email" query-param="Email"/>
         <with-param name="MobilePhone" query-param="MobilePhone"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
</data>
```

**DSS Call in Coding):**

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                        <format>
                            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:dat="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                                <soapenv:Header/>
                                <soapenv:Body>
                                    <p:Staging_Leads_Opr xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                                        <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
                                        <xs:Staging_LeadsTable xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$1</xs:Staging_LeadsTable>
                                        <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
                                        <xs:LeadID xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$body/jsonObject/Lead/Id/text()</xs:LeadID>
                                        <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
                                        <xs:Salutation xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$body/jsonObject/Lead/Salutation/text()</xs:Salutation>
                                        <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
                                        <xs:Type xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">Lead</xs:Type>
                                        <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
                                        <xs:FirstName xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$body/jsonObject/Lead/FirstName/text()</xs:FirstName>
                                        <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
                                        <xs:LastName xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$body/jsonObject/Lead/LastName/text()</xs:LastName>
                                        <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
                                        <xs:Email xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$body/jsonObject/Lead/Email/text()</xs:Email>
                                        <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
                                        <xs:MobilePhone xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$body/jsonObject/Lead/MobilePhone/text()</xs:MobilePhone>
                                        
                                    </p:Staging_Leads_Opr>
                                </soapenv:Body>
                            </soapenv:Envelope>
                        </format>
                        <args>
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('Staging_LeadsTable')"/>
                        </args>
                    </payloadFactory>
                    <call description="CarSalesDSS">
                        <endpoint key="CarSalesDSS"/>
                    </call>
```

**Management Console(TryIt tool):**

[image: ManagmentTryitTool]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved above mentioned issue by giving Input values in arg parameter of payload Factory Mediator.but still don't know why direct mapping is not working.

```
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                            <format>
                                <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:dat="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                                    <soapenv:Header/>
                                    <soapenv:Body>
                                        <p:Staging_Leads_Opr xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                                            <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
                                            <xs:Staging_LeadsTable xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$1</xs:Staging_LeadsTable>
                                            <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
                                            <xs:LeadID xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$2</xs:LeadID>
                                            <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
                                            <xs:Salutation xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$3</xs:Salutation>
                                        </p:Staging_Leads_Opr>
                                    </soapenv:Body>
                                </soapenv:Envelope>
                            </format>
                            <args>
                                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('Staging_LeadsTable')"/>
<arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body/jsonObject/Lead/Id/text()"/>
<arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body/jsonObject/Lead/Salutation/text()"/>
<arg evaluator="xml" value="Lead"/>

                            </args>
                        </payloadFactory>
                        <call description="CarSalesDSS">
                            <endpoint key="CarSalesDSS"/>
                        </call>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding the action header before the call mediator?

```
 <header name="Action" value="urn:Staging_Leads_Opr" scope="default"/>
```

Comment: Hi @Shanaka Premarathna,
Thanks for your response, tried the same but this action header didn't help me.